# Number of contiguous subsequence

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to calculate number of contiguous subsequences of length more than 1 such that no pair in that subsequence has a sum of k.

That is if a = { 1 , 3 , 4 } and k = 4
All contiguos subsequences include

```
{1,3} (sum of the only pair is 4)
{3,4}
{1,3,4} ( sum of one of the pair is 4 )
```

Then the valid subsequence is only {3,4} .. i.e the answer to my question would be 1.
Here is one more exapmle ...

a = { 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 } k = 4;
All subesequence include

```
{1,4}
{1,4,3} (sum of one pair is 4)
{1,4,3,2} (sum of one pair is 4)
{1,4,3,2,0} (sum of more than one pair is 4)
{4,3}
{4,3,2}
{4,3,2,0} (sum of one pair is 4)
{3,2)
{3,2,0}
{2,0}
```

There are 6 valid sequences in above answer

I dont even know how to start .

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array using a for loop. Grab the first item from the array, grab the next item from the array, if the sum of these 2 equals `k`, move on to the next item and repeat above step. If the sum does not equal `k`, you have a match.

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < (sizeof(a) - 1); x++) {
    if ((a[x] + a[x+1]) == k) {
        // no match
    } else {
        // match
    }
}
```

Obviously this example is extremely simple and you can definitely expand upon this but this is something to start with.

Comment: This is not a homework question , Its more like for self learning  .. and i found this in one of the textbooks .. I am a self learner . And I am sorry but didnt get you , Can you elaborate it a bit more >

Comment: Sorry, any question with a clear problem but no provided code is assumed homework by me. Kudos for self learning. You can easily check if numbers are sequential by a simple subtraction. if the difference is 1 then it is sequential. Hence, you have {3,4} in you example. And adding 3+4=7 is not equal to 4, you have a match. As far as looping through the array, you access items using an index. You can add 1 to that index, assuming it is numeric and not a string, and retrieve the next item to compare.

Comment: By sequential do you mean adjacent .. In the above example 1 , 3 ,4 is also a subsequence but it contains 1, 3 and hence is not a valid subsequence .

Comment: ah sorry, I read your question wrong. Yes, ignore the sequential part. I will update my answer.

Comment: Its okay , I updated my question for less confusion !! If the question had asked to not include only {1,3} , it would have been fine , but i dont know how not to include {1,3,4} .. I am trying for O(n^2) algo , a better than that would be great .

Comment: made a little change to my code. Notice I added `-1`. Added that to make sure you don't get out of bound in that if condition.

Comment: You are still assuming the pair has to adjacent .. The pair can be any of the two numbers .. I will add one more example.

Comment: You can add another loop inside this one to brag the items and compare all, i just wrote the above as an example and somewhere to start. Sorry can't write the whole code for you. Getting late. good night. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you need to get all intervals which it's length greater than one

then sort the sub array

then look for key in left side and right side of each element in sub array by binary search

java code:

```
int[] a  = {1, 4, 3, 2, 0};
    int k = 4;
    int n = a.length;
    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            if ((n - (i + 1)) > 0) {
                int[] subArray = new int[n - i];
                for (int h = j; h <= (n - (i - j + 1)); h++) {
                    subArray[h - j] = a[h];
                }

                // sort
                Arrays.sort(subArray);

                boolean exist = false;
                for (int h = 0; h < subArray.length; h++) {
                    int key = k - subArray[h];
                    // look for key in left side [0, h)
                    int index1 = Arrays.binarySearch(subArray, 0, h, key);
                    // look for key in right side [h+1, subArray.length)
                    int index2 = Arrays.binarySearch(subArray, h + 1, subArray.length, key);
                    if (index1 >= 0 || index2 >= 0) {
                        exist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                answer = !exist ? answer + 1 : answer;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
```

output:

> 6

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the array  from back side .

For eg:

Arrays is

> 1 , 2 , 3 ,1

At every point i , we will try to calculate the sub arrays which have sum K starting from i.

Let us keep an another array which tells us the minimum leftmost_Right_End of an index j in the right such that there exists a position e
( i< e < j ) 
A[e]+A[j]==K

Now whenever we are at position i the sub arrays starting from i th element 
should contain one pair , that pair can be formed due to the i th element or some element in the right !

Note: if we find minimum index of any pair such that A[x]+A[y]== K all the other z> y are waste for us as the condition says there should exist no pair such that A[x]+A[y]==K !

So the problem reduces to finding for each element i  index of K-A[i] if it exists and taking the minimum of this index from leftmost_Right_End . 
Now this index says that if the subarray starts from i then it should atleast extend till index found!
So the subarrays related to i are (N-i+1)

Now subtract the result from N*(N-1)/2

I have a code and I can explain better but self learning needs hints rather than solutions  :) . P.S. : I am a self learner too!

Answer (score 0):

Sort a value-to-index map of the array by value and use binary search to find all pairs that sum to `k`. Aggregate the pairs in an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Traverse the array one index at a time. When the current segment `(i,j)` overlaps one of the intervals in the tree, add `(segment_length ^ 2 - segment_length) / 2` to the total count, subtract the last overlapping count, and reset the traversing window to `(i + 1, j)`.

For example:

```
{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }

Sorted value-to-index map: { 0:4, 1:0, 2:3, 3:2, 4:1 }
Interval tree stores the intervals { (0,2), (1,4) }
```

Traverse:

```
{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total
  ^                       (i=0, j=0)      0

{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total
  ^   ^                   (i=0, j=1)      0

{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total 
  ^       ^               (i=0, j=2)      0

Match (0,2) => 
Add (2^2 - 2) / 2 = 1 to the total count (no previous overlap to subtract)
Reset window to (1,2)

{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total 
      ^   ^               (i=1, j=2)      1

{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total 
      ^       ^           (i=1, j=3)      1

{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total 
      ^           ^       (i=1, j=4)      1

Match (1,4) => 
Add (3^2 - 3) / 2 = 3 to the total count (no previous overlap to subtract)
Reset window to (2,4)

{ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 0 }      segment      total 
          ^       ^       (i=2, j=4)      4
```

Since the window is spanning the rest of the  array and there is no overlap with the tree, we can add the last segment subtracted by the previous overlap:

```
Add (3^2 - 3) / 2 - (2^2 - 2) / 2 = 2 to the total count

Total = 6
```